# How to add local variables to yylex function in flex lexer?

Tags: flex-lexer

I was writing a lexer file that matches simple custom delimited strings of the form `xyz$this is stringxyz`. This is nearly how I did it:

```
%{
char delim[16];
uint8_t dlen;
%}

%%

.*$ {
    dlen = yyleng-1;
    strncpy(delim, yytext, dlen);
    BEGIN(STRING);
}

<STRING>. {
    if(yyleng >= dlen) {
        if(strncmp(delim, yytext[yyleng-dlen], dlen) == 0) {
            BEGIN(INITIAL);
            return STR;
        }
    }
    yymore();
}

%%
```

Now I wanted to convert this to reentrant lexer. But I don't know how to make delim and dlen as local variables inside yylex apart from modifying generated lexer. Someone please help me how should I do this.

I don't recommend to store these in yyextra because, these variables need not persist across multiple calls to yylex. Hence I would prefer an answer that guides me towards declaring these as local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the (f)lex file, any indented lines between the `%%` and the first rule are copied verbatim into `yylex()` prior to the first statement, precisely to allow you to declare and initialize local variables.

This behaviour is guaranteed by the Posix specification; it is not a flex extension: (emphasis added)

> Any such input (beginning with a `<blank>`or within "%{" and "%}" delimiter lines) appearing at the beginning of the Rules section before any rules are specified shall be written to `lex.yy.c` after the declarations of variables for the `yylex()` function and before the first line of code in `yylex()`. **Thus, user variables local to `yylex()` can be declared here**, as well as application code to execute upon entry to `yylex()`.

A similar statement is in the Flex manual [section 5.2, Format of the Rules Section](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html)

---

The strategy you propose will work, certainly, but it's not very efficient. You might want to consider using `input()` to read characters one at a time, although that's not terribly efficient either. In any event, `delim` is unnecessary:

```
%%
    int dlen;

[^$\n]{1,16}\$ {
    dlen = yyleng-1;
    yymore();
    BEGIN(STRING);
}

<STRING>. {
    if(yyleng > dlen * 2) {
        if(memcmp(yytext, yytext + yyleng - dlen, dlen) == 0) {
            /* Remove the delimiter from the reported value of yytext. */
            yytext += dlen + 1;
            yyleng -= 2 * dlen + 1;
            yytext[yyleng] = 0;
            return STR;
        }
    }
    yymore();
}

%%
```

Comment: A quick follow up, if I want to return something additional other than just an int, something like the matched string itself, then should I use `yyextra` for that? or should I change `yylex` prototype like what bison-bridge does?

Comment: @sourav: up to you, and it depends a lot on how you're using the lexer. My preference: use a push-parser (bison / lemon / write-your-own). But that's me, and who is writing your parser is you.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/273602/241242) question I posted just now.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: Sorry, I don't do softwarerecommendations.SE; it's just not my style. You can usually speed up flex recognition by matching more characters per token, so what you suggest in that question might work, but you should benchmark it yourself using realistic inputs for your language. With some (but not all) standard library implementations, `strstr` is a lot faster than handwriting the loop; that might turn out to be faster. `memcmp` is almost always faster than `strncmp`; in cases where the semantics are correct, it should be used if possible....

Comment: You should forget that you ever heard of `strncpy` IMHO. If you know the length (which you do), use `memcpy`. If you really need the NUL-terminator (which you don't in this case), assign 0 to the terminating byte. But you don't require the copy at all, as I mention in my answer. Raw comments are probably not common enough in source code to really worry about efficiency, but if they were you'd really want to find a way to do them outside of flex, since they cannot be recognised with a regular expression which is truly regular (the kind that mathematicians talk about and flex uses).

Comment: Finally, `$` is a metacharacter in flex patterns, so it needs to be quoted or escaped.

Comment: Can you point me towards where you heard about `memcpy` being faster than `strncpy`. I just wanted to know..

Comment: I didn't make any claim about the speed of strncpy. You shouldn't use strncpy because it's dangerous and stupid except for its intended use case, which is fixed length string fields in database records. In that context, the fact that it doesn't null-terminate full records is fine and the fact that it clears the rest of the field is convenient. But you don't have that use case. For normal string copying, not null-terminating sometimes is dangerous and clearing beyond the end is a waste of cycles.

Comment: What I said was that memcmp is faster than strncmp. That shouldn't be surprising: it's easier to vectorise and it doesn't need to check every byte for zero.